# Surjectivity of a specific mapping of a continuous function to a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $T>0$ and let $f: [0,T] \to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function.

Define a sequence of numbers $(\gamma_i)_{i \in \mathbb N_0}$ in the following way:

$\gamma_i := \int_0^T \frac{(T-t)^i}{i!} f(t) dt.$

Question: Is the mapping $f \mapsto (\gamma_i)_{i \in \mathbb N_0}$ onto?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro : Yes, if f maps into $\mathbb R^n$ then it is actually a sequence of vectors. I will correct it in the question. Thanks

Comment: The change of variable $s=(T-t)/T$, and $g(s)=f(t)$, reduces the problem to the study of $$\gamma_n=\frac{1}{n!}\int_0^1 s^n g(s)\, ds.$$ This is somewhat similar to the classic moment problem, in which the sequence is $\sigma_n:=\int_0^1 s^n g(s)\, ds$ and $g$ is a probability density. This last mapping is not surjective; indeed, $\sigma_{n-1}-\sigma_{n}=\int_0^1(1-s)s^{n-1}g(s)\,ds\ge 0$, so any sequence that is **not** decreasing is out of the range. However, this does not prove that your mapping $g\mapsto \gamma_n$ is not surjective, because you do not require $g$ to be nonnegative.

Comment: I have posted a [follow-up question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3246220/8157).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No**, the mapping is not surjective. Note, indeed, that 
$$
\lvert \gamma_i\rvert\le \lVert f\rVert_\infty \int_0^T \frac{(T-t)^i}{i!}\, dt=\lVert f\rVert_\infty \frac{T^{i+1}}{(i+1)!}, $$
where $\lVert f\rVert_\infty = \sup\, \{\lvert f(t) \rvert\ :\ t\in [0, T]\}$.  Thus, any sequence $\gamma_i$ that does not satisfy the condition 
$$
|\gamma_i|\le C \frac{T^{i+1}}{(i+1)!},
$$
for some $C>0$, is out of the range. For example, the constant sequence $\gamma_i=1$ is out.